# Kafka cluster updated from PLAINTEXT to SASL_PLAINTEXT, cannot get Mirrormaker to work

Tags: apache-kafka

We have two separate kafka clusters in two datacenters and have configured Mirrormaker to replicate a set of topics. Each datacenter is running 3 nodes with kafka and mirrormaker. This setup is running correctly.

To enable more security, we need SASL_PLAINTEXT, or better SASL_SSL.

I configured SASL_PLAINTEXT in one of our datacenters on all three nodes:

Added in /etc/sysconfig/kafka:

`Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/kafka/kafka_server.jaas"`

Created /etc/kafka/kafka_server.jaas:

```
KafkaServer {
 org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
   username="admin"
   password="admin-secret"

};
KafkaClient {
  org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
  username="admin"
  password="admin-secret"
  ;
};
```

Changed listeners in /etc/kafka/server.properties:

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:443,SASL_PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:29093,SASL_SSL://0.0.0.0:29094
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://node1.app.gen.local:443,SASL_PLAINTEXT://node1.app.gen.local:29093,SASL_SSL://node1.app.gen.local:29094
```

Added to /etc/kafka/server.properties:

```
authorizer.class.name=kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer
allow.everyone.if.no.acl.found=true
security.inter.broker.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=PLAIN
sasl.enabled.mechanisms=PLAIN
super.users=User:admin
zookeeper.set.acl=false
```

After these changes a successful test has been performed on the first kafka node to test the SASL port like this:

```
export KAFKA_OPTS="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/kafka/kafka_server.jaas"
/u01/app/kafka/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:29093 --topic topictest1 --from-beginning --consumer.config=/etc/kafka/consumer.properties
```

/etc/kafka/consumer.properties:

```
security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
bootstrap.servers=localhost:29093
```

/etc/kafka/producer.properties:

```
security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
bootstrap.servers=localhost:29093
```

So the consumer on the newly created SASL port can read the existing topics in the cluster on which no ACLs have been set yet. This was also the expected behaviour.

The only problem now is that mirrormaker is broken between the new secured cluster and the second non secured cluster. Tried to fix it by making the following changes to the file that holds the consumer properties for mirrormaker: /etc/kafka/mirrormaker-consumer.properties

`bootstrap.servers=node1.app.gen.local:29093,node2.app.gen.local:29093,node3.app.gen.local:29093
        security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
        sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
        sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required \
        username="admin" \
        password="admin-secret";`

Mirrormaker starts, lots of entries in the DEBUG log, but the messages are not copied from the secured cluster to the (still) unsecured cluster.

What could I have missed?

Comment: I would suggest making some temporary topic for testing the CLI tools alone can produce an consume between the clusters you're interacting with. Once you have that working, use the same properties in the MirrorMaker configs

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, I solved this by your suggestion to test consumer and producer separately. It appeared that I had an ACL defined with topic '*' in there that prevented Mirrormaker's consumer to read the topics from its PLAINTEXT port.

What I have learned: if you put an ACL on a topic, it can no longer be read from the PLAINTEXT port :-)